# How do u use between operator for range?

Tags: sql, t-sql

This is my table Data

```
Id  Begin  End
1   0      1
2   1      3
3   3      4
```

This is my Query:

```
DECLARE @abc Float=1.5;
SELECT * FROM dbo.Slab  AS s WHERE @abc BETWEEN s.Begin  AND s.End
```

This give me 2 rows.  I want to find  a row for which  @abc parameter is greater than Begin but less or equal to End.For example if @abc=1 i want to select 1 , if @abc=1.5 I want to select 2 , if @abc=3 i want to select 2 , if @abc=0.1 i want to select 1 and so on.

Comment: `BETWEEN` is inclusive on both sides. Why not simply use `>` and `<=` operators?

Comment: `@abc` will never be `1.5` nor `0.1`, given that it's declared as an `int`.

Comment: oh sorry that is float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @abc Float=1.5;
SELECT * FROM dbo.slab  AS s WHERE @abc > s.[begin] and @abc<=s.[end]
```